# Combining 990 and 990-EZ Data

Tags: econometrics, labor-economics, finance, data-request, data

I've collected 990 and 990-EZ data from the IRS's Annual Extract of Tax-Exempt Organization Financial Data on American Federation of Musicians locals. The data are split about half and half between the forms. Some points of interest are membership dues, other revenues and expenditures.

The EZ form has an element for membership dues, but the standard form does not. I haven't found any clear documentation outside of the 200 page filing requirements document that may describe where I can find the related info on the 990 form. Has anyone had a similar issue, and if so, could you point me towards a resource to connect the relevant information?